# problema al mandar archivo por sockets TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Estoy empezando a enviar archvivos con sockets y python, en este caso un pdf

pero me arroja un error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\cliente.py", line 15, in 
>       cliente.send(str(len(buffer))) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Este es el codigo de el cliente:

```
import socket

CONEXION = ("Pc-1",900)
print(CONEXION)
ARCHIVO = "a.pdf"

cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(CONEXION)

with open(ARCHIVO,"rb") as archivo:
    buffer = archivo.read()

while True:
    print("Enviando bufer {}".format(buffer))
    cliente.send(str(len(buffer)))

    recibido = cliente.recv(10)
    if recibido == "ok":
        for byte in buffer:
            cliente.send(byte)
        break
```

Y esta es la del servidor:

```
import socket

CONEXION = (socket.gethostname(),900)
print(CONEXION)
servidor = socket.socket()

servidor.bind(CONEXION)
servidor.listen(5)

sck,addr = servidor.accept()
print("Conetado")

while True:
    recibido = sck.recv(1024).strip()
    if recibido:
        print("recibido",recibido)
    if recibido.isdigit():
        sck.send("ok")
        buffer = 0
        with open("archivo","wb")as archivo:
            while(buffer <= int(recibido)):
                data = sck.recv(1)
                if not len(data):
                    break
                archivo.write(data)
                buffer += 1
            if buffer == int(recibido):
                print("Archivo descargado con exito")
            else:
                print("Ocurrio un error")
        break
```

El error aparece en el lado del cliente me parece que al momento de leer el archivo.

Ya intente cambiando el archivo por otro o enviar otro tipo de archivo pero sale un error similar.

las pc estan en la misma red de trabajo, por lo que no pienso que sea un error de conexión o algo asi
Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python3 hay distinción entre una cadena de bytes y una cadena de caracteres.

El tipo `str` se refiere a cadenas de caracteres, pero los sockets sólo admiten cadenas de bytes, por lo que debes convertir unas en otras. También, cuando lees de un fichero obtienes por defecto cadenas de caracteres (a menos que abras el fichero en modo binario). En tu caso el fichero se está abriendo en modo binario, por lo que el problema no viene de ahí, sino de los "comandos" que has inventado para tu protocolo, como que el servidor responda con un "ok" (que es una cadena de caracteres, no de bytes), o que el cliente envíe primero la longitud en ASCII del fichero (que de nuevo es una cadena de caracteres, no de bytes).

Para convertir una cadena de caracteres a una cadena de bytes debes elegir un *encoding*. Cuando todos los caracteres son ASCII, el *encoding* puede ser `"ascii"`, pero en el caso más general en que quieras enviar texto arbitrario (con acentos o eñes) el estándar es usar UTF-8.

De este modo, cada vez que necesites enviar por un socket algo que tengas en una cadena de caracteres (`str`) tienes que convertirlo en bytes, con un código como el siguiente:

```
txt = "Texto a enviar por el socket"
sck.send(txt.encode("ascii"))  # o utf-8
```

Y cuando lo recibas, tendrás una cadena de bytes y si quieres operar con ella como si fuera de caracteres (un string) deberás decodificarla, con un código como el siguiente:

```
recibido = sck.recv(1024)
txt_recibido = recibido.decode("ascii")  # o utf-8
```

Ten en cuenta que ambas partes de la comunicación deben usar el mismo encoding.

Y ten en cuenta que lo que lees de tu fichero pdf, ya que lo has abierto en modo binario, será directamente una cadena de bytes, la cual no requiere ser codificada ni decodificada.

En tu caso lo que debes codificar a la hora enviarse, y decodificar a la recepción sería:

- La longitud del fichero que el cliente envía en forma de cadena.
- El "ok" que el servidor envía tras recibir esta longitud.

### Actualización, explicaciones adicionales

Para enviar la longitud inicial tenias `str(len(buffer))`. Ya que como hemos dicho las cadenas "normales" no se pueden enviar sin antes convertirlas a bytes, para arreglar esto no basta con quitar el `str()`, pues dejarías `len(buffer)` que es un entero, no una cadena de bytes. La solución sería algo como esto:

```
tamanio = str(len(buffer))
cliente.send(tamanio.encode("ascii"))
```

Sin embargo no está claro que esto vaya a funcionar como pretendes. En el lado servidor tienes un:

```
recibido = sck.recv(1024).strip()
```

en el que parece que esperas justo el `tamanio` que el cliente acaba de enviar. Si por ejemplo el tamaño era de 12423 bytes, el cliente habrá enviado la cadena (de bytes) co los dígitos "12423". Ya que en el servidor no sabes cuántos dígitos ha enviado, has optado por poner 1024 para que pueda recibir "de sobra" (si hay menos retornará sólo los que encuentre).

Esto te funcionará correctamente la mayoría de los casos, y el servidor recibiría la cadena (de bytes) "12423", que tendrías que convertir a cadena de caracteres con algo como `recibido = recibido.decode("ascii")` para poder procesarlo seguidamente con `recibido.isdigit()` o `int(recibido)` como hace tu código.

Sin embargo también podría darse el caso, dependiendo del estado de saturación de la red, de la diferencia de velocidades entre cliente y servidor y de otros factores, que el cliente haya enviado la cadena (de bytes) "12423" y seguidamente, antes de que los datos hayan podido llegar al servidor, haya entrado en el bucle que envía los bytes del fichero y haya enviado unos cuantos.

En ese caso, cuando el servidor vaya a hacer `sck.recv(1024)` podría encontrarse con la cadena (de bytes) "12423" e inmediatamente después con los primeros bytes del fichero, todo en una sola lectura. La variable `recibidos` tendría "pegado" la cadena que representa la longitud del fichero junto con los primeros bytes de éste. No hay forma de saber qué es qué, dónde acaba la longitud y dónde empieza el fichero.

Y es que TCP es un protocolo *orientado a flujo*. Lo que lees del socket es un flujo de bytes que no corresponde necesariamente con los "trozos" en que ha sido escrito. Puedes escribir los bytes de 20 en 20 y leerlos de 2 en 2, o viceversa.

Así pues la idea de enviar primero la longitud del fichero se complica, ya que sería necesario que delimitaras de alguna forma dónde termina esa cadena que indica la longitud. Por ejemplo, podrías poner un `\n` al final de la misma. Pero el servidor también se complica puesto que tras leer los primeros 1024 bytes debería buscar dónde está ese `\n` para determinar que lo que está delante es la cadena que indica la longitud y lo que está después ya es parte del fichero.

Si este protocolo lo vas a usar para transferir *un único fichero*, puede ser mucho más simple que no envíes ninguna longitud, sino directamente el fichero. Si te preguntas ¿cómo sabrá entonces el servidor cuándo parar de leer? la respuesta es muy simple. El cliente, tras enviar el último byte del fichero cerrará el socket. En el servidor, cuando la función `sck.recv()` le devuelva una cadena vacía (o sea que su `len()` sea cero) sabrá que el socket se ha cerrado y por tanto que el fichero está completo.

Un último detalle para mejorar la eficiencia. No tienes por qué escribir los bytes de 1 en 1 y leerlos de 1 en 1. Puedes escribir bloques de cualquier tamaño (por ejemplo de 1024) y leerlos en bloques de cualquier otro tamaño. Funcionará igual si vas concatenando lo leido. El ultimo bloque será necesariamente más corto, pero ni siquiera necesitas tratarlo de forma especial.

Comment: funciono pero ahora me lanza un error similar en la linea 21 del cliente este es el error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\cliente.py", line 21, in <module>
    cliente.send(byte)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'`

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez Creo que tienes algunas confusiones. He extendido la respuesta para añadir más explicaciones y detalles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, me ayudo mucho