# Sockets no envia texto

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexion cliente sevidor utilizando sockets en python3.

Lo que busco realizar es que se puedan intercambiar archivos entre uno y otro al mandar un mensaje.

En este caso la maquina servidor pregunta al usuario que documento desea recibir de el cliente en este caso un pdf.

El servidor manda el mensaje `pdf` al cliente y el cliente manda el archivo `.pdf` al servirdor despues de eso el cliente deberia de mandar al servidor el texto `ok` y de esta manera el servidor entra en espera para recibir un mensaje nuevo

Sin embargo el cliente al momento de terminar de enviar el archvio `.pdf` no envia el texto

este es el codigo:

cliente:

```
import socket

cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(("Pc-1",900))


with open("a.exe","rb") as file:
    bufer=file.read()

lenBuf = len(str(len(bufer)))
print(lenBuf)
cliente.send(str(lenBuf).encode("ascii"))
print(len(bufer))
cliente.send(str(len(bufer)).encode("ascii"))
recibido = cliente.recv(3)
if recibido.decode("ascii") == "pdf":
    cliente.send(str("enviando").encode("ascii"))
    f = open("a.pdf","rb")
    l = f.read(1024)
    while l:
        cliente.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)
        if len(l)==0:
            texto = "okok"
            cliente.send(texto.encode("ascii"))
```

servidor.

```
import socket

CONEXION = (socket.gethostname(),900)
servidor = socket.socket()

servidor.bind(CONEXION)
servidor.listen(1)

pdf = "pdf"
mp3 = "mp3"

sck,addr = servidor.accept()

longitudBuffer = sck.recv(1)
print(longitudBuffer.decode("ascii"))
longitudFile = sck.recv(int(longitudBuffer.decode("ascii")))
print(longitudFile.decode("ascii"))
sck.send(str("pdf").encode("ascii"))

f = open("file2.pdf","wb")
while True:
    l1 = 1
    verificacion = sck.recv(8)
    if verificacion.decode("ascii") == "enviando":
        while True:
            l = sck.recv(1024)
            while l:
                f.write(l)
                l = sck.recv(1024)
                if len(l)==0:
                    break
            if len(l) == 0:
                l1 = 0
                break
    if l1 ==0:
        break
nuevo = sck.recv(1024)
print(nuevo)
```

Comment: Parece que, tal como lo tienes, el servidor lee todo lo que recibe del cliente hasta que éste cierre el socket, y lo guarda en el fichero recibido. Por tanto cuando el cliente le envíe el "ok", lo considerará parte del fichero recibido. Comprueba si efectivamente el fichero que guardas en el servidor tiene al final del mismo "ok". El problema es que TCP no delimita entre envíos. Tienes que implementar como parte del protocolo una forma de diferenciar cuándo envías bytes del fichero u otra cosa parte de tu protocolo.

Comment: Por otra parte, el código de esta pregunta se parece al de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273244/problema-al-mandar-archivo-por-sockets-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-require) publicada también hoy ¿eres el mismo usuario?

Comment: @abulafia,no pero de esa pregunta tome el ejemplo de codigo para probarlo ya que estoy tambien viendo sockets en la universidad pero he tenido problemas con ello, como este,

Comment: @abulafia, puedes ayudarme

Comment: @abulafia, gracias ahora estoy intentando romper los bucles cuadno la longitud sea 0 pero aun nada sigue sin enviar el texto.

Comment: @abulafia, editare mi codigo para que veas que he estado intentando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## El problema de TCP

El problema es que el protocolo TCP es un protocolo *orientado a flujo*.

Visualízalo como una tubería que une los dos sockets, y por la que puedes ir metiendo "bolitas" (que serían los bytes). Todo lo que hace el protocolo es garantizar que las "bolitas" llegarán todas al otro lado, en el mismo orden en que fueron introducidas, pero no garantiza que lleguen en paquetes cuyo tamaño puedas conocer de antemano.

Es decir, imagina en tu ejemplo que el fichero ocupa 2058 bytes. Tal como tienes implementado el código del el que envía, el bucle se ejecutará tres veces, una para leer de fichero (y enviar por el *tubo*) 1024 bytes, otra para otros 1024 y una tercera para leer los 10 que quedaban y enviarlos también.

### Los *short-writes*

En realidad la cosa es más compleja, porque es posible que al intentar enviar los 1024 primeros, en realidad en la "tubería" sólo haya sitio para por ejemplo 1000 (pues en realidad por debajo TCP usa diferentes buffers, algoritmos anti-congestión, etc.) En ese caso `send()` enviará sólo lo que se pueda (1000 en el ejemplo). Para contemplar esta eventualidad deberías recoger el valor retornado por `send()` que te dice cuántos ha enviado en realidad, y ocuparte tú de actualizar tus variables para que en la próxima iteración del bucle envíe lo que habia quedado sin enviar (es decir, si había enviado 1000, enviar los 24 que faltaban, antes de leer otro bloque del fichero).

Eso es muy farragoso, y Python te da la función `socket.sendall()` que se ocupa de resolver este problema. Lo que hace esta función es lo que tú pensabas que hacía `socket.send()`, es decir, no retornar hasta haber enviado todo (insistiendo con sucesivos envíos si no cabe todo en uno).

Por simplificar, supongamos que no aparece este problema y que realmente en cada `send()` consigues enviar los 1024 bytes. O bien cambia `send()` por `sendall()` y ya tenemos esta suposición garantizada. En este caso el bucle de envío se ejecutaría tres veces como antes dije, para enviar en cada iteración 1024, 1024 y 10 respectivamente.

### La recepción

Al final en el "tubo" habrá 2058 "bolitas", las cuales pueden ser leidas en "trozos" del tamaño que quieras. Este "tubo" en realidad está compuesto de múltiples buffers intermedios. Puede que las 2058 bolitas estén aún todas en un buffer local de la máquina que envía, y que aún no haya salido ninguna a la red. Puede que hayan salido parte a la red (quizás las 500 primeras) y el resto estén aún en el buffer local. Puede que hayan salido todas y ya no quede nada en el buffer local, y estén por ahí en tránsito. Puede que una buena parte de ellas hallan llegado ya a destino y estén en otro buffer esperando a ser leidas por un `recv()`. Puede que incluso hayan llegado todas y estén las 2058 en el buffer de destino, esperando ser leídas.

La clave que debes comprender es que *no hay forma de saber cuántas han llegado a destino* hasta que no intentes leerlas. Si aún no llegó ninguna, `recv()` se bloqueará, hasta que lleguen algunas. Si habían llegado, `recv()` te retornará todas las que hubieran llegado, hasta el máximo que le especifiques (1024 en tu caso).

Ese 1024 no es el número de bytes que vas a leer, sino el máximo que admites en esa lectura. Las que realmente leerás *pueden ser menos*. Y no existe una función `socket.readall()` que se quede esperando hasta tener las 1024.

Por tanto en tu línea `l = sc.recv(1024)` lo que te encuentres en la variable `l` al retorno tendrá *como máximo* una longitud de 1024, pero puede ser menos. No importa mucho, porque sea cual sea la longitud de `l`, eso lo vuelcas a disco y repites el bucle para recibir otra tanda.

En resumen, que aunque el emisor pudo enviarlo todo en tres tandas de 1024, 1024, 10, el receptor puede sacarlo del socket en muchas más tandas, si le van llegando en grupos más pequeños, debido a problemas en la red. Sea como sea, lo que sí está garantizado es que llegarán todas tarde o temprano y en el mismo orden, por lo que el fichero se podrá reconstruir sin problema.

Aún así *vamos a suponer también que no tienes este problema*, y que realmente cada vez que llamas a `recv(1024)`, te retorna 1024 bytes, salvo la última vez en la que hay menos.

### Delimitadores (o el problema del *framing*)

Tu código aún así tiene otro problema, y es que el emisor no se ha limitado a enviar el fichero, sino que ha añadido al final un "ok". Es decir, en vez de 2058 bytes, ha enviado 2060. Aunque este "ok" lo envía luego, en otro `send()`, recuerda que en el fondo eso simplemente lo coloca en "la tubería" tras los otros 2058 que ya había.

Cuando el receptor haga el último recv(1024), en vez de los 10 últimos bytes del fichero, recibirá 12. Los 10 últimos y el "ok" final.

El problema es que no hay delimitadores en los mensajes. Es decir, en el flujo de bolitas que hay dentro del tubo, no hay forma de diferenciar las que componen el fichero de las que componen otros mensajes que envías.

La solución a esto es que inventes un protocolo que lo distinga. Tienes típicamente dos opciones:

1. Enviar al principio de la comunicación un número que indique cuántos bytes son el fichero. Entonces quien reciba, debe ir contando cuántos ha escrito recibido y al alcanzar ese número sabe que lo que venga detrás será parte de otro mensaje.
2. Incluir algún byte especial "marcador" que indica que se terminó un mensaje y empezó otro. El problema aquí es ¿y si el byte elegido como marcador formaba parte de los bytes a transferir del fichero? No habría forma de diferenciarlos.

Naturalmente tienes una tercera opción. No mezclar mensajes en la misma conexión TCP, sino cerrar el socket cada vez que envíes un mensaje completo. En ese caso el que recibe el mensaje itera sobre `recv()` hasta que `recv()` retorne una cadena de longitud cero. Esto indicará que la conexión fue cerrada (y no que el cliente haya enviado cero bytes, eso no puede ocurrir).

## Conclusión

Cuando hayas digerido todo esto y hayas elegido una forma de implementarlo (es decir, hayas inventado *tu protocolo*), puedes plantear una nueva pregunta si sigues teniendo problemas.

Comment: te agrazesco la explicación sin embargo aun no logro hacer que funcione. Muchas gracias seguire investigando